# split string using regex and extract result by group

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a string using a regex expression, but I failed to find the correct expression, 
this is below the code  used and also the expected result you can run the code  in https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/

and replace may regex by the correct one thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] result   = RegexServiceBusiness("19922 test ibaraki, hamari-shi, hamari 3456789");

      System.out.println("street : " + result [0] + " and the city is : "+ result [1] + " and the full city is : "+ result [2]);
    }

    public static String[] RegexServiceBusiness(String input) {

        String street = null;
        String city = null;
        String fullCity = null;
        String[] result = new String[3];

        String regex = "(.*)(\\w+-shi)";// this regex expression should match the string giving.
        Matcher matcher;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        matcher = pattern.matcher(service);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            street = matcher.group(0);
            city = matcher.group(1);
            fullCity = matcher.group(2);
        }

        result[0] = street;//19922 test ibaraki
        result[1] = city;//, hamari-shi
        result[2] = fullCity;//, hamari-shi, hamari 3456789

        return result;
    }
}
```

other example and output :
"19922 test hatachi karashi-shi hamari 3456789"

expected output 
**street**:19922 test hatachi
**city**:karashi-shi
**fullCity**: karashi-shi hamari 3456789

Comment: Can you please add the expected output? That is, what should be the 3 parts from the input string you have in the code?

Comment: you can find them inside the code provided as comment thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using split, you could use 3 capturing groups and nest the 3rd group inside the 2nd group and make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^,]+` matching any char except a comma, and match 0+ horizontal whitespace characters `\h*` in between

```
([^,]+),\h*((\w+-shi),\h*[^,]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQbcSQ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/GOeUNH)

For example

```
String regex = "([^,]+),\\h*((\\w+-shi),\\h*[^,]+)";;
String string = "19922 test ibaraki, hamari-shi, hamari 3456789";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // 19922 test ibaraki
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); // hamari-shi, hamari 3456789
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // hamari-shi
}
```

---

Matching what is on the left and on the right of the word containing `-shi`

```
(.+?)((\w+-shi).+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJvPOT/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/t9TrnF)

Comment: thx a lot for answering my problem is that  i have to pick anything before the word conatining -shi as street what ever comma or without or anycharacter, the word wontaining -shi as city and the what after plus the word conatining -shi as full city

Comment: @TarikHandaz Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/pQbcSQ/1 I have updated the answer.

Comment: not exactly I just added another example in the post the main word to split with is the word containing -shi doesn't matter what before and what after

Comment: @TarikHandaz If there can be anything before and after https://regex101.com/r/bJvPOT/1

Comment: bro you are the best could you update your answer to match your last comment